# preg_replace incorrect or strange behaviour in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a complitely reproducible example, which demonstrates strange behaviour of PHP `preg_replace` function. So, I have two files with such content:

```
//new.txt
<!-- start -->Replacement 2\1<!-- end -->

//before.txt
<!-- start -->Text to replace<!-- end -->
```

When I do this:

```
$regex = "`<!-- start -->(.*?)<!-- end -->`";
$replacement = file_get_contents("new.txt");
$target = file_get_contents("before.txt");
$after = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $target);
echo $after;
```

it prints:

```
<!-- start -->Replacement 2Text to replace<!-- end -->
```

which is indeed incorrect. But when I do this:

```
$regex = "`<!-- start -->(.*?)<!-- end -->`";
$replacement = "<!-- start -->Replacement 2\1<!-- end -->";
$target = "<!-- start -->Text to replace<!-- end -->";
$after = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $target);
echo $after;
```

it prints:

```
<!-- start -->Replacement 2<!-- end -->
```

which is more correct (though, as you can see, the last "\1" disappeared). BTW, if I remove "\1", both examples start to work correctly. So, how can I fix it?

Comment: I wonder why people are voting down, even though I provided reproducible examples and my own code snippets.

Comment: Besides, please, pay attention, that I said "incorrect or strange behaviour", so I'm not insisting that it is some PHP bug. Probably, I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: So, if I asked some stupid thing, why not to point to this stupidity? What for is this silent voting down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big mix of different things is happenning here.

(I've gone with a supposed expected result of `<!-- start -->Replacement 2\1<!-- end -->`)

For the first topic, in regex replacement, `\1` is a *backreference*. This will be replaced by the chars matched in the first parenthesis in the pattern.
It could also be written as `$1`.

You can use numbers from 1 to 99. You can find more info here in [PHP doc for regexes](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) and for [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (see `replacement`)

This explains why the `\1` is replaced by `Text to replace` as this is the part matched by `(.*?)`

The second thing is to remember the difference between single quoted `('str')` and double quoted strings `("str")`.
In single quoted strings, the backslash doesn't have a special meaning (except to escape a single quote : `echo 'str\'str'` produces `str'str` or to escape itself : `echo 'str\\str'` produces `str\str`).
But in double quoted strings, backslash has special meaning and introduces an escape sequence (`\n`, `\r`,...) and can also represent a char in octal notation. This happens here in your 
second string. It's a double quoted string and `\1` is replaced with the `SOH` char, which is not a visible char.

The third thing is that a string read from a file is not changed like a double or single quoted string, you get it exactly like it is in the file.

The solution :
You need to escape the backslash, but how many times needs ?

- Condition : the preg_replace function needs to recieve this exact sequence of char `\\1` so it doesn't see it as a backreference, after changes made to escape sequences if any.
- In the **text file**, as backslash is not interpreted, use : `<!-- start -->Replacement 2\\1<!-- end -->`
- In the PHP code file, in a **single** quoted string, `\\` produces `\` and `\1` is not changed : use `'<!-- start -->Replacement 2\\\1<!-- end -->'`
- In the PHP code file, in a **double** quoted string, `\\` produces `\` and `\1` is seen as octal char : use `'<!-- start -->Replacement 2\\\\1<!-- end -->'`

Now you'll get addicted to the backslash...